# Can GRUB be installed to separate drive that doesn't contain a Linux system?

Tags: grub2, bootloader, disk, mbr

As the title says, can GRUB be installed to separate drive that doesn't contain a Linux system?

For example, let's say I have two disks: `sda`, and `sdb`.

Let's say the partition layout is something like this (completely hypothetical):

```
Disk     Partition     Filesystem     Size     Contents
--------------------------------------------------------
sda
         sda1          NTFS           256GB    Windows 7 OS
         sda2          NTFS           500GB    Data

sdb
         sdb1          NTFS           128GB    Some more data
         sdb2          Unallocated    750GB    -
```

Is it possible to install GRUB to the MBR of `sda`, while installing Ubuntu to `sdb2` so that `sdb` doesn't have to be first in the boot order? (Leaving the MBR of `sdb` blank)

#### Assume the motherboard only supports MBR booting.

Comment: This should not be a problem. I have had some installations that installed from USB and accidentally GRUB was installed on USB instead of hard drive. After that the Linux from the hard drive could only be started when USB was inserted. So, I see no problem in doing the way you want it. Of course you have to configure BIOS to boot from the right drive.

Comment: @nobody - The thing is, I tried it in a VM and it told me that "bootloader installation was failed".

Comment: @AndroidDev That sounds more like a VM setup problem than a GRUB issue.

Comment: @ZeissIkon - Why? It was the Ubuntu installer that was saying that. FYI, this is going to have to work in a VM before I accept and answer. I'm not going to wipe my disk just to test this :)

Comment: I'm not a VM expert.  Maybe the need for this to work in a VM before you install on an actual device should be part of the question (or another question).  Make that change to this one, and I'll delete my answer as no longer relevant.  For whatever it's worth, this worked first time for me without a VM in sight (there wasn't a good VM available for free when I started using Linux).

Comment: @ZeissIkon - Well, let me play around with it and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: If you install in a VM, you install on a virtual disk. I think you have to install Grub to the MBR of this virtual disk. The virtual disk is not existing as long as the host-system is not running. If you install to a real disk, you can install Grub to the place of your choice, just choose `Something eslse`-option to install. You could install Grub to MBR of any existing disk or even to a PBR (only make sense withe more then one distro installed and chainloading), but in a VM, I think you don't have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can.  When I first installed Linux (before I switched to Ubuntu), I had a full HDD with Windows and several storage partitions, and a smaller drive with room for Linux.  Since the system booted from the Windows drive, when I installed Linux, GRUB went on the Windows drive.  That was what's now called Legacy Grub, and worked fine, but it will also work with GRUB 2.  All that's required is that Grub be on a bootable partition, your system's startup ROM knows to boot from the volume with GRUB, and GRUB must have the correct volume identification (UUID is most reliable) for each system it will launch.